# (63)File name too long: access to /xyz failed referer:www.mydomain.com

Tags: php, apache, yii

Recently I have enabled encryption in my urls.It worked fine for 95% urls.But in only some pages using pagination I'm getting 403 error.When I checked apache error log,I got this error.I'm using Yii framework,apache 2.2,PHP 5.3.Any Idea?

```
(63)File name too long: access to  /xyz failed referer:www.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Is the `/xyz` real path in logs? If not, how many symbols are there?

Comment: Maybe helping: http://serverfault.com/questions/388858/how-to-fix-file-name-too-long-error-in-apache2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation in Apache2

Make sure your anything between 2 slashes is not longer then 255 characters.

When you have an argument/filename longer then 255 chars, Apache will check this against your file system limits.

Info on the max filename length can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

There aren't a lot of them that allow for longer file names, so you will have to make them shorter, no other way around them.

If you really need Urls encrypted with more than 255 characters suggest using Mod-Rewrite + Yii UrlManager to break into arguments over multiple splashes, alternatively restrict your encryption algorithim to encrypt with less than 255 characters.