# How to make apache not to ignore ErrorDocument 404 with in ᴜʀʟ which contains a?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

## Note: the supposed duplicate is about how to access files with long names, but in my case, I don’t even want to check for it’s existence and have /_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz being used instead.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz
```

Which when the document contains a ? and a long ᴜʀʟ after it results in a 403 error:
For example accessing `/_ah/conflogin?state=~AJKiYcGTxysMayaAQSUXMAm3sKBrvlKLrR73oI_W8LXwAbHHy6M61MQ3SyI4md2Abg2Y_DWAlPPdH5nDKaB1Wafg3KKMltgR3WIcvkhV0aOlPbQ9TX21wOTXIcyhGPz4fCe6x_AT3XdIfDk2zqQ2mxCUW45qKhtNPFxG4SHzKg6sRuJPPF2o3QITLMZHbwS2yDQLaIuc298ROAUVu_3sgl0G9YZbM6K_mZEAqeI3zCX5MmG41eUfiX2wSxsSNPCLWQ24LAFuqOu4An9GqLYD4ycAh-EQKGG8P_2iKOYmkOcZytYeEF9I`

triggers a HTTP 403 page with this error in the log:

```
[Sat Apr 13 17:26:29 2019] [error] (63)File name too long: access to /_ah/conflogin?state=~AJKiYcGTxysMayaAQSUXMAm3sKBrvlKLrR73oI_W8LXwAbHHy6M61MQ3SyI4md2Abg2Y_DWAlPPdH5nDKaB1Wafg3KKMltgR3WIcvkhV0aOlPbQ9TX21wOTXIcyhGPz4fCe6x_AT3XdIfDk2zqQ2mxCUW45qKhtNPFxG4SHzKg6sRuJPPF2o3QITLMZHbwS2yDQLaIuc298ROAUVu_3sgl0G9YZbM6K_mZEAqeI3zCX5MmG41eUfiX2wSxsSNPCLWQ24LAFuqOu4An9GqLYD4ycAh-EQKGG8P_2iKOYmkOcZytYeEF9I failed (filesystem path '/www/y/ytrezq/_ah/conflogin?state=~AJKiYcGTxysMayaAQSUXMAm3sKBrvlKLrR73oI_W8LXwAbHHy6M61MQ3SyI4md2Abg2Y_DWAlPPdH5nDKaB1Wafg3KKMltgR3WIcvkhV0aOlPbQ9TX21wOTXIcyhGPz4fCe6x_AT3XdIfDk2zqQ2mxCUW45qKhtNPFxG4SHzKg6sRuJPPF2o3QITLMZHbwS2yDQLaIuc298ROAUVu_3sgl0G9YZbM6K_mZEAqeI3zCX5MmG41eUfiX2wSxsSNPCLWQ24LAFuqOu4An9GqLYD4ycAh-EQKGG8P_2iKOYmkOcZytYeEF9I')
```

So how to make apache not ignore the ErrorDocument directive if the requested ᴜʀʟ is too long ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(63)File name too long: access to /xyz failed referer:www.mydomain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541132/63file-name-too-long-access-to-xyz-failed-refererwww-mydomain-com)

Comment: @bishop no as I don’t even want to access that file doesn’t even exist. It should only check for `/_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz` and without redirecting first.

Comment: The posted error message say this `/_ah/conflogin?state=~...`, but you assert the file is at `/_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz`. Perhaps you want `/_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz?state=~...`.

Comment: @bishop no i don t care about the ?. I want this static file to be served and without any redirect.

Comment: It's not a 301. The first URL redirects to the second one via a Javascript `document.location`. So, the first request being a 200, there's no chance your ErrorDocument directive is going to be triggered. Not sure where you see a 403 in there.

Comment: @Capsule I had to compile a C ᴄɢɪ script in order to fix the problem so the link in the question no longer triggers the problem. In terms of performance, I’m still interested in doing it with what’s meant for, that is `ErrorDocument`.

Comment: `I don’t even want to access that file doesn’t even exist` - how will Apache know to use an `ErrorDocument` if it doesn't know the file doesn't exist? It needs to process the URL, discover it does not exist, and then use your ErrorDoc.  And it is telling you it can't process it bcs it is too long.

Comment: @Don'tPanic good point ! But in that case if it fails to check the file exists it should use the `ErrorDocument` instead of ignoring it (adding an `ErrorDocument` is no help).

Comment: That makes no sense.  It is telling you very plainly what the problem is.  It has not gotten as far as checking if the file exists, and it will not, until you solve the error it is telling you about.  You can't just hope an ErrorDoc will be used no matter what the circumstance.  It sounds to me like you are approaching this from entirely the wrong direction. If you don't care if the file exists, why not use a simple internal redirect? Though I expect you will still hit the same "too long" problem.

Comment: @Don'tPanic because while I care if the file exists the question is not about accessing files that can’t exist or can’t be reached even normally.

Comment: Hang on. What's you understanding of `ErrorDocument 404`? You're asking Apache to deliver a custom page (/_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz)  for any 404 encountered, not to return a 404 when accessing /_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz (it's the other way around).

Comment: @Capsule no, I would never ask Apache to serve a document more than 255 characters name long. So checking if such files with more 255 characters exists is irrelevant.

Comment: @user2284570 that's not what I said. I'm asking what is your expected result because I'm not sure you get what `ErrorDocument 404` is for. Please edit your question and state: URL accessed, expected result.

Comment: @Capsule done now.

Comment: It's still confusing you are trying to access the 404 file itself, as /_ah/conflogin?state=.... will probably resolve to /_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz. Plus, the filename is not too long. It has a long query string but that shouldn't impact the request. Does you CGI make a request in the background trying to access a state file that IS too long? Please provide a URL that allows us to replicate the 403 error you're seeing.

Comment: @Capsule `you are trying to access the 404 file itself, as /_ah/conflogin?state=.... will probably resolve to /_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz` That’s the point of the question : why it doesn’t ? The ᴄɢɪ script doesn’t try to check if files with more than 255 characters exists and sends `/_ah/conflogin/index.html.gz`instead. I .You can reproduce my question through using a ErrorDocument 404 directive like mine and create a request to a file which don’t exists where the nonexisting filename is longer than 255 characters.

Comment: But what doesn't make sense is the filename is not too long, it's just a query string

Comment: @Capsule exactly, this is a query string but the problem is Apache doesn’t treat it like this.

Comment: Do you get the same error when accessing any URL with a very long query string on your server?

Comment: @Capsule I don t understand what you mean as the filesystem itself doesn t support such long filenames (and that I don t have superuser rights on the hosted server).

Comment: Try to access anything, like `/test/?blah=` then paste a very long string and see if you get the same 403, or your custom 404. Just trying to rule out anything specific to that URL your testing and seem to involve some CGI script? Alternatively, you should consider another host...

Comment: @Capsule yes the problem appears with any url with such long string. Instead of using the 404 page specified in errordocument, it ignore the directive and returns a blank 403 page.